# express server on node.js returning 501 for patch calls

Tags: node.js, express, server-error

I'm at a loss with a problem that been bugging me for a few days.  My express server is returning me 501s for all patch calls.  (I believe they used to work).

Does anyone have any suggestions or a way that I could debug express to find where my problem is coming from?

Here's some info:

My route call

```
app.patch('/creator/sentences/:masterId/', require('./views/creator/sentences/index').updateMaster);
```

What I get on the client:

```
Request URL:http://my-url.c9users.io/creator/sentences/197/
Request Method:PATCH
Status Code:501 Not implemented
```

Any help would be appreciated or anyone someone thinks I could find a way to debug this.

Comment: Have you tried adding some form of logging on the express side such as Morgan? If so what does the output say?

Comment: @IvajloDonev I just added it but there's no output for the PATCH call, if I switch to PUT I get a 404 as expected.  Also removing the route call also gets 501 so obviously not something I am doing myself, in fact any patch call going to the express server  returns a 501.  But my understanding is that express supports patch (I'm on the latest version).

Answer (score 0):

I ended finding out that for some reason my ISP was blocking patch calls.  Any other network and things were fine... Went on VPN and things were fine...  So weird and now I understand why some web sites weren't working properly for me.
Patch calls must just be quite rare if the isp has this problem they don't fix.

EDIT AND SOLUTION:  I ended up using https instead of http and then my isp couldn't block the patch requests :)

Comment: The fact that your ISP tracks down and blocks some HTTP Verbs should really worry you. Anyway, good thing you found out the cause of your problem. ^^

Comment: I know... it was unsettling.  I couldn't believe it for a while but it really seems to be the case.  Either that or it's my router but I went on it and there are no such settings.  I'm in the Philippines right now.  So I'm not sure if it's done on purpose or just a mistake.  I noticed it started 3 days ago.  I think it's just a bug on some tracking software the isp must be using.

Comment: Actually I just switched to https and everything worked out :)

Comment: Normal, the Http header is then encrypted (including the Verb, the cookies, etc). Unless they have a certificate installed on the machine, they can't know much, so they can't block it. ^^